# Why is `compile()` needed for `exec()`?

Tags: python, exec

My module `path = "..\blah\blah\myfolder\mymodule.py"` contains:

```py
print('hi')
```

Code execution:

```py
exec(compile(open(path, 'rb').read(), path, 'exec'))
```

and

```py
exec(open(path, 'rb').read())
```

give the same result.

Why is `compile()` needed?

Comment: Obligatory [eval is evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice) plug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are identical in your case, i.e. `exec` and `eval` use `compile` if get the string as an input. But `compile` can be used to precompile the code that will be repeatedly executed with `exec` (or `eval`), making it run faster because you don't need to compile the code each time. Consider:

```
compiled_code = compile(open(path, 'rb').read(), path, 'exec')
for _ in range(10**9):
    exec(compiled_code)
```